# Black gradient background on Action bar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm confused how to add the following black gradient to Action Bar.
I search a lot for this, but I couldn't find the same. 
I have seen this gradient in many apps, moreover it's not a drawable file maybe drawable xml file.
I tested by making gradient file but gave no exact result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first example from [blog post](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/)

You'll need to create ab_background.xml with gradient action bar.

Comment: Cool, thanks.
It worked, I guess I should've searched more better.